# Custom Comparators to reflect multiple changes as well as deeper diffs

Tags: javers

I am attempting to implement CustomComparators for certain classes. The first question I have is how to return back multiple ValueChanges in my CustomComparator. I seem to only be able to return back a single ValueChange on that object when more than one field might have changed. Additionally, I can't figure out how to get Javers to generate a diff for objects that appear as fields in the class my CustomCommparator is overriding. Example below:

I have the following classes defined below where we have a Person owning a Store that has an Item they sell there.

```
public class Person
   public Store store


public class Store
   public String name
   public Item item
   public String location

public class Item
  public String name
```

Question:
1. How can I implement a CustomComparator for Store such that it creates two ValueChanges: one for name and one for location. 
2. How can I use that same CustomComparator to get Javers to also do a diff on item? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, you can't. The `CustomPropertyComparator.compare()` method returns `PropertyChange` which can be complex object (like `ListChange`) or any kind of object that extends PropertyChange. But still, PropertyChange describes a Change on exactly one Property.

Doing it javers-way means registering CustomValueComparator for each Value Type.

For example, if you have the Item class:

```
class Item {
    Price price
    Characteristics Characteristics 
}
```

Register custom comparators for each atomic Value Type:

```
javersBuilder
    .registerValue(Price.class, (a,b) -> a.compareTo(b) == 0)
    .registerValue(Characteristics.class, (a,b) -> a.compareTo(b) == 0)
```

Comment: For example, I have a class `Item` with two float fields, `Item.USprice` and `Item.UKprice`. I want to round both prices before comparing and return `ValueChange` for each of the fields if they change. I also have a field called `Item.Characteristics` that is an object and I want to diff on that object as well. Changing the class `Item` is not an option either. @Bartek