# Compare value objects using a custom comparator

Tags: javers

I want to compare value objects in a way that null properties are ignored.
More specifically, I only want to include those properties of a value object in the comparison which are not-null on the *right side*.
E.g.

```
class Person {
  String name;
  String surname;   
}


Person personLeft = new Person();
personLeft.name = "John";
personLeft.surname = "Doe";

Person personRight = new Person();
personRight.name="John"


// this should NOT yield any changes
javers.compare(personLeft, personRight);


// that comparison however, will show that surname has changed
javers.compare(personRight, personLeft);
```

I though I could tackle this problem by writing a custom comparator and registering it for `Person`.
Unfortunately this comparator is never called.
Stumbling upon that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045748/custom-comparators-to-reflect-multiple-changes-as-well-as-deeper-diffs/45090850#45090850), I fear that this is not possible using a custom comparator for the `Person` class.
Instead I would have to register custom comparators for all containing value types of the Person class, i.e. `String`.

Is that the intended use of javers or are there any alternatives to that approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is important here is that `CustomValueComparator` can be used only for Value types. So you have 2 options:

1. Map Person as Value and then you implement diff algorithm for
   Person. It works but is awkward because Person is more like an
   Entity.
2. Register a CustomValueComparator for Strings (all Strings), and then you can use Person as Entity. That's the option that I would choose.

See how it works (groovy):

```java
class Entity {
    @Id int id
    Person person
}

class Person {
    String name
}

def "should use CustomValueComparator for Person when Person is mapped as Value"(){
  given:
    def javers = JaversBuilder.javers().registerValue(Person,
            { l, r -> if (r.name == null) return true
                      else return r.name.equals(l.name)
            }).build()

    def personLeft = new Person(name: "john")
    def personRight = new Person()

    def eLeft = new Entity(id:1, person: personLeft)
    def eRight = new Entity(id:1, person: personRight)

  expect:
    javers.compare(eLeft, eRight).changes.size() == 0
    javers.compare(eRight, eLeft).changes.size() == 1

    javers.getTypeMapping(Person) instanceof ValueType
}

def "should used CustomValueComparator for Strings"(){
  given:
    def javers = JaversBuilder.javers().registerValue(String,
          { l, r -> if (r == null) return true
          else return r.equals(l)
          }).build()

    def personLeft = new Person(name: "john")
    def personRight = new Person()

  expect:
    javers.compare(personLeft, personRight).changes.size() == 0
    javers.compare(personRight, personLeft).changes.size() == 1

    javers.getTypeMapping(Person) instanceof ValueObjectType
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will go for the 2nd approach using a CustomValueComparator.